# Insert sum of two value automatically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to do something like this but i am kind of stuck in here.

So i have a table with header column as

Fe Ni Co Magnetic NonMagnetic

below each item, i have input box of value in which user can enter value.

In the above table Fe, Ni are magnetic and Co is Non-magnetic.
So, when user enters value under Fe and Ni, its sum get automatically inserted Under Magnetic and if he enter value for Co, its value will get inserted under NonMagnetic.

I have tried using id of box below item name and id of item but was unable to get this done. I want to do all this using html and javascript.
This is just a part of code. Whole code is way bigger. So i don't want to confuse, so i am just putting context of part code.

If anyone can suggest me some ways to do it. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this like so:

```js
const feInput = document.getElementById('fe');
const niInput = document.getElementById('ni');
const coInput = document.getElementById('co');

const magnetic = document.getElementById('magnetic');
const nonMagnetic = document.getElementById('non-magnetic');

function updateMagnetic() {
  const fe = feInput.value;
  const ni = niInput.value;
  
  magnetic.innerHTML = Number(fe) + Number(ni);
}

function updateNonMagnetic() {
  const co = coInput.value;
  nonMagnetic.innerHTML = Number(co);
}

feInput.addEventListener('input', updateMagnetic);
niInput.addEventListener('input', updateMagnetic);
coInput.addEventListener('input', updateNonMagnetic);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fe</th>
      <th>Ni</th>
      <th>Co</th>
      <th>Magnetic</th>
      <th>NonMagnetic</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="fe" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="ni" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="co" type="number" /></td>
      <td id="magnetic">0</td>
      <td id="non-magnetic">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```